# Index action not displaying flash notices

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, controllers

I have a trackers_controler with a destroy action.  I am trying to redirect the destroy action to the index on destroy because all these trackers are displayed in a summarized table in index.

On my destroy action, When I redirect to tracker_url my flash notice appears correctly.  But the URL has the id (as it should)

```
 redirect_to tracker_url, :notice => "Tracker Disabled!"
 redirect with the flash notice displaying
 /trackers/trackers/5
```

When i redirect to index using the redirect to below, it shows the flash notice in the url but doesn't display the flash notice in a message.

```
redirect_to :action => index, :notice => "Tracker Disabled!"
redirects without the flash notice
/trackers?notice=Tracker+Disabled%21
```

To debug, i have copied the code from index.html.erb and show.html.erb so that they are identical and still gt the flash notice as part of the url even thought they both have the render for messages in the same spot.  The partial for messages is in the layouts/messages folder

```
<%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
```

Below are my show and index

```
def index
   authorize! :view, :silver, :message => 'Access limited to Silver Plan subscribers.'

   @new_tracker = Tracker.new
   @current_user = current_user
   @trackers_enabled = Tracker.enabled.where(:user_id => @current_user.id)
   @trackers_disabled = Tracker.disabled.where(:user_id => @current_user.id)
 end

def show
   authorize! :view, :silver, :message => 'Access limited to Silver Plan subscribers.'

  @new_tracker = Tracker.new
  @current_user = current_user
  @trackers_enabled = Tracker.enabled.where(:user_id => @current_user.id)
  @trackers_disabled = Tracker.disabled.where(:user_id => @current_user.id)
end
```

From my development log here is the posts after the redirect

```
SHOW
```

Redirected to /trackers/1
Completed 302 Found in 19ms (ActiveRecord: 13.8ms)

Started GET "/trackers/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-14 11:06:06 -0500
Processing by TrackersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}

```
INDEX
```

Redirected to /trackers?notice=Tracker+Disabled%21
Completed 302 Found in 19ms (ActiveRecord: 13.5ms)

Started GET "/trackers?notice=Tracker+Disabled%21" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-14 11:06:51 -0500
Processing by TrackersController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"notice"=>"Tracker Disabled!"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line has problem

```
redirect_to :action => index, :notice => "Tracker Disabled!"
```

The notice part becomes param of #index in your code, instead of argument of `redirect_to`.

To fix, use named path. Suppose your index page path is `trackers_path`, then

```
redirect_to trackers_path, :notice => "Tracker Disabled!"
```

Comment: It's often desired to not have to restate the entire path to redirect to when in the context of a specific controller. In which case differentiating the path hash from the options has would accomplish this: `redirect_to({ :action => index }, :notice => "Tracker Disabled!")`